# Python remove only alphabet elements from a list

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I have a very messy data, I am trying to remove elements that contains alphabets or words. I am trying to capture the elements that have alphanumerical and numerical values. I tried .isalpha() but it not working. How do I remove this?

```
lista = ['A8817-2938-228','12421','12323-12928-A','12323-12928',
             '-','A','YDDEWE','hello','world','testing_purpose','testing purpose',
        'A8232-2938-228','N7261-8271']
lista
```

Tried:

```
[i.isalnum() for i in lista] # gives boolean, but opposite of what I need.
```

Output:

```
['A8817-2938-228','12421','12323-12928-A','12323-12928','-','A8232-2938-228','N7261-8271']
```

Thanks!

Comment: loop through each element in the list, then loop through each character in that string. if it's a non-letter, add it to another string. that string is then your output

Comment: what is the desired output for the example you posted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add conditional checks in list comprehensions, so this is what you want:

```
new_list = [i for i in lista if not i.isalnum()]
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
['A8817-2938-228', '12323-12928-A', '12323-12928', '-', 'testing_purpose', 'testing purpose', 'A8232-2938-228', 'N7261-8271']
```

---

Note that `isalnum` won't say `True` if the string contains spaces or underscores. One option is to remove them before checking: (You also need to use `isalpha` instead of `isalnum`)

```
new_list_2 = [i for i in lista if not i.replace(" ", "").replace("_", "").isalpha()]
print(new_list_2)
```

Output:

```
['A8817-2938-228', '12421', '12323-12928-A', '12323-12928', '-', 'A8232-2938-228', 'N7261-8271']
```

Comment: Does this match the intended output?

Comment: @DanielMesejo The OP presented `str.isalnum` method so I took it directly. Further checking isn't the core idea of this question (but yeah it'd be useful if I had time to add it).

Comment: Op forgot to mention that spaces are considered to be alphanumeric in their definition

Comment: @MadPhysicist Fortunately I have time to update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

What type your data in the list?

You can try to do this:

```
[str(i).isalnum() for i in lista]
```

Comment: This won't match OP's desired output.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can just test at least one character is a digit *or* equality with `'-'`:

```
res = [i for i in lista if any(ch.isdigit() for ch in i) or i == '-']

print(res)

['A8817-2938-228', '12421', '12323-12928-A', '12323-12928',
 '-', 'A8232-2938-228', 'N7261-8271']
```